# Is there an analog of initComponent a method of Ext.create?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I want to do some init, when I use **Ext.create("....")**. The object is simple and small, and I don't want to define it, but it need some method from mixin (before component create called)... How can I do it?

Comment: I assume you already tried adding initComponent inside `create()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Standard Instance Overrides

---

- Typically, we would use `Ext.override()` after `Ext.create()` to apply overrides to a specific instance of a class (see [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-override)) :

  ```
  var myObj = Ext.create('Ext.some.Component', {
      ...
  });

  Ext.override(myObj, {
      myMethod: function() {
          // Do something.
          this.callParent(arguments); // From Ext.some.Component class.
          // Do something else.
      }
  });
  ```
- `this.callParent(arguments)` works properly ***only*** for overrides created

  - explicitly via `Ext.override()`, or
  - implicitly via `Ext.define()`

## Special Case: overriding `initComponent`

---

- Since the `initComponent` method is called *during* the execution of `Ext.create()`, we must override it within `Ext.create`.  In order to access the original method, we must use a work-around to access the overridden method:

  ```
  var myObj = Ext.create('Ext.some.Component', {
      initComponent: function() {
          // Do something.

          // Get a reference to the class.
          var myClass = Ext.getClass(this);

          // Apply the overridden method from the class' prototype.
          myClass.prototype.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);

          // Do something else.
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: This leads to a `stackoverflow` (ironic :P) error. The `myClass.prototype.initComponent.apply(this, arguments)` call will recursively call the same function over and over again.

Comment: It shouldn't because the function on the prototype and the component instance are not the same (see http://jsfiddle.net/VrA4T/). Although with further testing, it appears that this technique does not work with the constructor method.

Comment: Hmm.. strange.. works in your example. In my case it went berserk. I guess ppl should try it out and see if it fits their scenario..

Comment: @VarunAchar Are you certain you were testing this in `Ext.create()` and not `Ext.define()`? `Ext.create()` should not overwrite the prototype's `initComponent`.

Comment: Hmm.. you caught it.. :) .. Yeah.. I was working with `Ext.define()`. Trying to override the base functionality in the extending class and then calling the Parent of the class I was extending.

Comment: Okay, in the case of `Ext.define()`, `this.callParent(arguments)` will work within any override method.

Comment: In my case I was trying to override the `initComponent` method. `this.callParent` will call the parent's method, which I didn't want to do.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're doing something along the lines of:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    prop1: value1,
    prop2: value2
});
```

If that's the case, you should be able to add a property called initComponent which is a function that does what you want. Just remember to call the original initComponent so everything gets built correctly:

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    prop1: value1,
    prop2: value2,
    initComponent: function () {
        this.doSomething();
        Ext.panel.Panel.prototype.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please note that `this.callParent(arguments)` is not compatible with a method defined via `Ext.create`, please see my answer for more details.

Comment: It really shouldn't work, `Ext.create` is not for overriding methods, it's for instantiating an object and setting config. If you need to override a method, you need a subclass (`Ext.define`).